# Netstat continuous refresh (watch changes the output)

Tags: linux, debian, netstat

I am using this simple command to monitor connections (to deal with some recent DoS attacks) on my Debian server:

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

How do I run it continuously? So it will refresh itself once per minute (or any given amount of time, of course). I tried watch:

```
watch -n 30 "netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n"
```

But it changed the output from nice list with num of connections to something like this:

```
1 tcp        0  10015 [LOCAL IP]
...
1 Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
1 Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
```

So external IP is not being displayed. Is there something I missed?

This is how the original output looks:

```
  2 [IP ADDRESS]
  4 [IP ADDRESS]
  4 [IP ADDRESS]
  4 [IP ADDRESS]
  7 [IP ADDRESS]
 16 [IP ADDRESS]
 71 [IP ADDRESS]
```

And when I say `[LOCAL IP]` I mean my machine's IP.

When I run it with `-c` it just freezes.

Comment: Are you running watch with root privileges? The command looks sound and seems to behave how I would expect on my machine. Running without will not print the addresses and, after 30 seconds might print an error message.

Comment: @StewartPlatt I run it under root. I added the original command output. The thing is, when I do watch - it outputs only *my* IP address ad does not output connected to me IPs at all.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
netstat -c
```

may help you if i've not misunderstood your problem. -c stands for --continuous.

EDIT:
there you go:

```
watch -n 30 "netstat -ntu | awk '{print \$5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n"
```

I've added a \ before $.

Comment: already tried, sorry I didn't specify this in a question. It just freezes when I add -c.

Comment: I realized that, the $5 is removed at the output of watch. Maybe there's a quotation mark issue. I'm digging on it..

Comment: thank you, good to know about escaping special chars in watch

Answer (score 5):

Searching for command for macos ends up here. For those mac user who want to see the real-time connections of a process:

```
nettop -p 60683
```

You can also restrict the interface type, like wifi or wired...

```
nettop -t wifi -n -p 60683
```

Answer (score 3):

Monitoring on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, this worked well. It displays good human-readable output.

```
sudo netstat -tupnc
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run a while loop that sleeps for 60 seconds

```
[root@host] $ while true
> do
> netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
> sleep 60
> done
```

This will give you the same output every 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

you can use netstat interval(in second)
it refresh active connection in each interval
for example type in cmd: netstat 5 -> this mean every 5 seconds, netstat runs again until you press Ctrl+C